# Java VMs that do not require an operating system?

Tags: java, jvm, vmware, virtualization, xen

I know that BEA was working on LiquidVM which didn't require an underlying operating system, but would like to know if anyone in the open source community is working on something similar.

Ideally I would like to find an implementation where the VM is directly loaded by the OS boot loader.

Comment: what kind of system were you intending to write apps for?

Comment: Haha, nice question. I love hearing about projects like these.As a small aside,  I remember reading about an open source project that got CPython(The standard python implementation) to run on bare-metal and were working on building an OS in python :) Sadly I've lost the link since.

Comment: Remember this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS

Comment: As of 2023 have a look at the native code generation of graalvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is it you need?

Perhaps Sanos can give you a small chunk of code between the hardware and the JVM which you can use?

http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/

Comment: Does Sanos support JDK 1.6 and/or 64-bit?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Latest is 1.4.    It is Open Source so if you need it, feel free to join.

Comment: So will SANOS die because it hasn't generated enough community interest?

Comment: No idea.  Ask the project developer :)

Answer (score 15):

Unlike SANOS, the [JNode](http://www.jnode.org) operating system is a full operating system with many supported devices, file systems, a network stack, a GUI stack, a command shell and 50 or so commands, and much more.  JNode currently runs on x86 (32 bit) with one processor enabled, but x86-64 and multi-processor versions are in development.  (JNode is 99.99% Java. Porting to a new architecture would entail rewriting the 0.01% of code that is in assembler, creating / modifying hardware specific drivers ... and writing a native code compiler for the new architecture.)

We currently have ~7 active developers, but we are always looking for new people to join the team, especially people who understand Java AND code generation, garbage collectors, drivers and so on.

(And for what it is worth, we use a recent version of the OpenJDK class libraries: 1.6u24 at the last count.)

Comment: Link appears to be broken. Found this: http://jnode.ro/node/936

Answer (score 4):

There is the Sun project [Squawk](https://squawk.dev.java.net/) which a VM that runs on hardware instead of an underlying OS. Useful for embedded devices like the [Sun SPOT](http://research.sun.com/projects/squawk/squawk-sunspot.html) where Squawk is the OS.

Squawk is licenced under GPLv2.

Comment: Do note that Squawk is pretty much dead, and isn't particularly recent (I think it's still at 1.3), so I wouldn't recommend it for any new developments.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Project Guest VM](http://research.sun.com/projects/dashboard.php?id=185), which is a JVM hosted on Xen hypervisor. While the home page seems to be rather light on details, there's a [Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHIaH12f2Ek) about this project as well.

Comment: It's indeed a very interesting and promising project. You should edit your answer and add also a reference to maxine: https://maxine.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 2):

[JNode OS](http://www.jnode.org/) is an operating system written mostly in Java.

Comment: Any thoughts on how JNODE compares to SANOS?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle seems to work again in that direction

> Gained with Oracle's acquisition of BEA Systems ...
>   Oracle has resuscitated avant-garde
>   virtualization technology: a Java
>   Virtual Machine that runs directly on
>   the hypervisor, without an operating
>   system.

see

- [Virtualizing the JVM](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid94_gci1510355,00.html)
- [Oracle one-ups VMware with Java virtualization](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/4304)

Answer (score 1):

JOE, Java On Everything, can run Java without an OS. It is all Java and at https://github.com/joekoolade/JOE

> JOE can run a Java program without an operating system by building the operating system into the program. This makes the program easier to configure and deploy. JOE can make any Java programmer an embedded developer.
>
> JOE is a process virtual machine that can run a Java application without an operating system. It builds the OS into the program by virtualizing the OS and hardware. This removes the boundaries between the OS, hardware, user code, and virtual machine. The overhead and complexities in the user/supervisor crossing, program security, memory protection, virtual addressing, and the JNI library interface are replaced with simpler and more efficient mechanisms found in the Java language. JOE seamlessly blends those layers together by implementing them all in Java. This virtualized Java environment provides a secure, safe, cohesive, and consistent object oriented operation from application to hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small snippet I seen and heard.

MIT in the 60's/70's developed a Lisp machine, this was a machine that intrinsically understood Lisp, I think that they went onto commercialize it also.

I had heard in about 2002 that someone was doing to develop a JVM on a chip a FPGA or ASIC.

The MIT/Lisp story is true, I seen it in their museum, does anyone know if there is any truth about the JVM on a chip?

thanks,
Martin.

Comment: Some ARM CPUs have http://www.arm.com/products/multimedia/java/jazelle.html - although I don't know if it's a full-featured JVM or not (my gut feeling says probably not)

Comment: Jazelle is *not* a fully-featured JVM, it's just support that allows the CPU to execute *some* byte-code instructions and thus make it easier to write a performant JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to java and and i have some knowledge of electronics.

JVM is a virtual macjine which actually run over a system. It may be windows or solares x86 platform.
But as far as i know JVM itself act as a system  for the Bytecode that we compile. For a byte code JVM virtualise its own ALU, Heap, Stack extra. It even have its own machine and assmbly language.

So  some how if we able to realize a JVM specification on a Hardware chip then it will not be JVM anymore but i will become standalone Java Machine over which we can develop a operating system 100% written in java.

So in this case JVM will not be an OS but a System which directly understand java bytecode.