# Run java app like a OS

Tags: java, operating-system, raspberry-pi

Yes, it's not clear from the title and maybe it's not feasible
I'm interested in a way to make a java app (with UI, made with JavaFX) like a OS: It should load when the system load, and should show the UI at fullscreen like the normal desktop. The system should be installed on a pc like Raspberry Pi or a VM with VirtualBox (for testing).
It is possible?
Sorry for the strange question
Thanks

Comment: There are some attempts to write Java window managers, I don't know of any that are production ready.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java VMs that do not require an operating system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763438/java-vms-that-do-not-require-an-operating-system)

Comment: yes, but that post was written 3 years ago, maybe something changed!

Answer (score 4):

You're probably mixing up the OS with the desktop environment / window manager.

You probably want to install a regular OS, such as Raspbian, and auto-launch your Java application when the OS has booted.

This thread might be useful: [Start ubuntu without a desktop environment but start an X application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application)

Comment: But I should disable the UI of the OS, how?